# What is the name of the manufacturer of this Chinese made bicycle?

Tags: road-bike

I have a Trac (no 'k') Forever 200 bicycle from China (complete with Chinese writing on it). Any idea who the manufacturer is? Is this bike common in China? I can't find anything online about them.  Thanks.

Comment: Take a photo and post it, please.

Comment: I've been in Beijing for 8 months but never saw a brand called Trac. I don't  know any good bike brand from China either.

Comment: @azer89 IMO Upland makes some excellent bikes. If I was buying new I'd buy an Upland any day over American or Taiwanese brands.

Answer (score 5):

Shanghai Forever company ltd
[www.forever-bicycle.com](http://www.forever-bicycle.com)

From [Time Out Shanghai](http://www.timeoutshanghai.com/features/Shopping__Style-Shopping_features/8575/Shanghais-best-bike-shops.html)

> There are many places across Shanghai to pick up classic Yongjiu (Forever) bikes.

And from a [post on JLA Forums](http://www.jlaforums.com/viewtopic.php?t=356629425):

[image]

Comment: This seems like one of the very few times a link-only answer is acceptable. A little research suggests it's correct. Wow! I pasted in some details just on general principles, hope that's ok.